# How can I make a span text overflow, like an input

Tags: css, overflow

I am trying to achieve this with a span:

[image]

This is what I have:

```
<span>some text goes here</span>

span{width:50px;overflow:hidden;float:left;}
```

This gives me this:

[image]

I tried every possible way I could think of but the text keeps moving downwards. I don't want to specify the height.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap`. Otherwise the content will always expand the box vertically.

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1574267)

Comment: Thank you. Pretty much what I was looking for

Comment: Hi, @nikc.org. That works almost like an input text, but with one important difference: when an input text overflows, the "overflowed" content is the beggining. I means, I want the overflow occurs on the left, keeping visible the last part of text. I tried a solution explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side), but it has a bug when we use special caracters on text. I will really appreciate some help here.

Comment: @robsonrosa Hi, you should open a new question.