# How to get the reverse behavior of the CSS property "text-overflow: ellipses"?

Tags: css

I tried the following code:

```css
#my-div{
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="my-div">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you notice, the 3 dots replaces the last part of the sentence in the div because of the overflow. How can I reverse that behavior? Is it possible to replace the first part of the sentence with 3 dots (i.e. hide the overflow from the beginning NOT the end)?

Comment: You might find some ideas here: 1) [Text-overflow ellipsis on left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side), 2) [overflow to truncate from the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761418/i-need-an-overflow-to-truncate-from-the-left-with-ellipses), and 3) [reverse ellipsis](https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `text-align: left;` and `direction: rtl;` in CSS, it will work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRwoGZ

**CSS**

```
#my-div{
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    direction: rtl;

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="my-div">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me in Firefox 54 and Chrome 59, but not in Safari 10.1.1.

Comment: Just export from my codepen and open in safari. It is working.

Comment: Ok, but this ONLY works when the div allows only one line. My div needs to have certain number of lines (depending on its height) and after filling those lines, the overflow begins. How to do it?