# Truncate a string at the beginning

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am doing a `text-overflow: ellipsis` in a div to truncate some extremely long text values. Basically to avoid the overflow from increasing the width of the div since there is no white space in URL. What I need to do is display the following:

```
http://www.somewebsite.org/over-the-counter/drugs/medone.html
http://www.somewebsite.org/over-the-counter/drugs/medtwo.html
http://www.somewebsite.org/over-the-counter/drugs/medthree.html
```

as:

```
...he-counter/drugs/medone.html
...he-counter/drugs/medtwo.html
...-counter/drugs/medthree.html
```

Is this doable at-all in HTML/CSS? or is jQuery/PHP my only resolve?

BTW, upon mouseover the full string is displayed as a tooltip.

Comment: php [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) comes to mind

Comment: javascript or php would be the way to go. (preferably php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side

Comment: Thanks. I wish https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow (direction: rtl) was more widely adopted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$short = '...'.substr($url, -20);`

In tooltip just show `$url`

Comment: Right. I know how do it in PHP, the good thing about using CSS is that the truncation is dynamic. `O` for examples takes more pixel space than `i`. CSS text-overflow auto calculates and puts the ellipsis according to the div width.

Comment: the bad thing about css or anything client side is its not reliable, some user will have a browser that does not support it, that cant happen if you do it server side

Comment: It's not much different in javascript... `short = '...' + (url.substr(-20));`

Comment: @RohitChopra In this instance, a monospaced font would solve your problem (and would be a good fit for this type of data).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with pure CSS and `direction` property set to `rtl` (right to left) on the container.