# Needs use right "text-overflow" when "direction" is set to "rtl"

Tags: direction, css

I need to put "..." in the front of text and show only last part of it, when it fills div.

And do nothing when it is normal

```
<span class="file-upload-status" style="max-width:200px">
    C:\fakepath\996571_1398802860346752_2094565473_n.jpg
</span>
<br/>
<span class="file-upload-status" style="max-width:200px">
    C:\fakepath\1.jpg
</span>
```

Here is what i have : http://jsfiddle.net/CBUH4/5/

Here is what i need : [image]

Is it possible to do by Css, without using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: A simple `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will work in Firefox, but I dont think any other browser does it the way you have mentioned.

Comment: I tried `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but it damages to `direction: rtl;`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS, but if you are OK with JS, I can give a solution.

Comment: @SahakSahakyan, what do you mean by “but it damages to `direction: rtl;`”? Doesn’t the title of the question mean that you *want* right-to-left directionality?

Comment: I will try to run this script when value changes. But CSS solution will be great.

Comment: Yes @Jukka K. Korpela. I dont need to show 'C:\fakepath\...'

Comment: Duplicate of [Text-overflow ellipsis on left side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9793473/1577396). but I am not closing this post because the linked post has no perfect css solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CBUH4/8/

```
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Just one point mate. In Firefox, when the text is "One Two Three" and `ellipsis` is applied it becomes "... Two Three". But in other browsers it becomes "...One Two Th". The user wants the former.

Comment: @Mr_Green: That is strange. I am using Chrome Version 31.0.1612.2 dev-m. If it works fine, then it is great :)

Comment: @Harry I am using chrome version 29.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Ok, you are using the latest stable version and I am using a development version. If it is working in the stable version, then let us hope it doesnt change :)

Comment: I use crome Version 29.0.1547.57 and its look [link]https://lh6.ggpht.com/A-RFe4N4gQ6V1Ni6G2ZIGQZTZLiSF4R5c5Ld-ogmvox_kgsP_eo6yiQZM1U09BCOJL7wJA=s170

Comment: @SahakSahakyan yeah that is what I can see from here. It is not perfect but it is close to what you want.

Comment: @Mr_Green: I think that is where the issue is. User doesn't seem to want "..C:\fakep", he rather wants "...\fakepath".

Comment: Sorry @Mr_Green but it is not so close. I have a big form where file uploads are changed whit jQuery, there is no any `<input type="file" />` displayes. And i want user to see his selected file last chars, when its name is bigger than 200px, for differ them, because there is always 'C:\fakepath' or same folder path in the front of filename.

Comment: well then maybe something like this, with a pseudo element :before that will overlay the div. http://jsfiddle.net/CBUH4/12/

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic that is merging both :after elements to one. and then you are positioning at the element which required ellipsis.  (Honestly, you wasted my time to understand what magic you did there). :D

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic this solution doesn't work when the last char is a symbol like '@'. Tested in Chrome and IE11. I will really appreciate some help to solve this bug. I dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest solution I could have got using just css. Still it has a drawback that we need to use multiple `.`'s which are approximately equal to the width of the span element.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBUH4/14/)**

**HTML**

```
<span class="file-upload-status ellipsis" style="max-width:200px">
    C:\fakepath\996571_1398802860346752_2094565473_n.jpg
</span>

<br/>
<span class="file-upload-status" style="max-width:200px">
    C:\fakepath\1.jpg
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.file-upload-status {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 27px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.file-upload-status:after {
    content:".................................";
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
.file-upload-status:before {
    content:"...";
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Suggestion: Give as much dots as possible :D

Comment: Having a look at the image that is shown in OP, I just modified it a bit (that is apply rtl only for the div with ellipsis). Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/CBUH4/11/). Feel free to add it to the answer if you are OK with it :) +1 for the sample.

Comment: Its good. But I must use Javascript to add `ellipsis` class to span when value in it is long :)

Comment: @SahakSahakyan ya seems so.. I am still trying.. but no luck :(

Comment: @SahakSahakyan I updated my post. It is somewhat more close now :)

Comment: @Harry I updated my post. (pinged you assuming you might be interested for the solution).

Comment: @Mr_Green: Yup, I am keeping track of this one mate. I have it in my Fav's list also :)

Comment: Thanks you all for looking into my problem. Still no changes in my browser :) I've decided to leave it as it is

Comment: @SahakSahakyan which browser it is? and what is the version?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62 m