# Text overflow with ellipsis on the left

Tags: html, css

Consider this html/css snippet:

```css
.l { text-align: left; }
.r { text-align: right; }

p { 
  width: 150px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: solid 1px green; 
}
```

```html
<p class="l">111222333444555666777888999</p> 
<p class="r">111222333444555666777888999</p>
```

It shows two fixed-width containers with some text too long to fit, with overflow set to show an ellipsis to show that some text is hidden. The first container is left justified, the second is right justified.

The result shows that the ellipsis is on the right for both examples.

However, for the second right justified one, I'd like to achieve this:

```
...4555666777888999
```

instead of

```
1112223334445556...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the direction of text from right to left using css direction property `direction: rtl`:

```css
.l {
  text-align: left;
  direction: rtl;
}
.r {
  text-align: right;
}
p {
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<p class="l">111222333444555666777888999</p>
<p class="r">111222333444555666777888999</p>
```

> **direction**
>
> Set the direction CSS property to match the direction of the text: rtl
>   for languages written from right-to-left (like Hebrew or Arabic) text
>   and ltr for other scripts. This is typically done as part of the
>   document (e.g., using the dir attribute in HTML) rather than through
>   direct use of CSS.

**References**

[MDN direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Comment: IE11 shows `...111222333` instead of `...4555666`

Comment: This is unfortunately not a general purpose solution. `<p class="l">0.example.com</p>` renders as `example.com.0` in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Found a solution: start your content with `&lrm;` to force the content itself to be rendered as regular left-to-right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957443/strange-special-characters-issue-in-left-side-ellipsis

Comment: Safari also displays `...1112223334445556` -_-|||

Answer (score 2):

To get this effect you have to use a little hack. See the following example:

```css
p {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:150px;
}
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.reverse-ellipsis {
  text-overflow: clip;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}
.reverse-ellipsis:before {
  content: '\02026';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -1em;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.reverse-ellipsis span {
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-indent: 0.5em;
}
.reverse-ellipsis span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: 200;
  left: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<p class="ellipsis reverse-ellipsis">
  <span>111222333444555666777888999</span>
</p>
<p class="ellipsis">111222333444555666777888999</p>
```

More information about this you can find here: http://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/