Make text-overflow on the left without changing direction
Is there a way to add the text-overflow ellipsis on the left side without changing the direction? Basically i just want to show the rightmost part of an absolute linux file path correctly:


.filepath {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  direction: rtl;  
}
<div class="filepath">/home/user/folder/subfolder/file</div>



This results in something like .../subfolder/file/, but i need just .../subfolder/file

You can either wrap the text in a  tag, or add &lrm; as the first character. Either way, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957443/strange-special-characters-issue-in-left-side-ellipsis, as I'm not sure if "without changing the direction" makes it different enough.
