# Show ellipsis on right side and align text to right

Tags: css, flexbox, direction

I put  `direction:rtl;`  to show in reverse order, but I want to truncate extra text at right side, but not left side.

```css
   .file-upload-status {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="file-upload-status" style="width:200px">
<span>*</span>
   <span></span> C:\fakepath\996571_1398802860346752_2094565473_n.jpg</span>
</div>
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: How do you need output?

Comment: C:\fakepath\996571_1398802860346752.... *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Needs use right "text-overflow" when "direction" is set to "rtl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532256/needs-use-right-text-overflow-when-direction-is-set-to-rtl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removing direction: rtl and adding below solves my problem

```
.file-upload-status {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden; 
   display : flex; 
   flex-direction : row-reverse; 
   align-items: flex-start;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

}

Comment: yes, the dots appear on the left side, but the text is still rendered from left to right and not from right to left. We need the text to be displayed from the right to left

Answer (score 1):

Used text-align:right instead of direction:rtl

```
 <div class="file-upload-status" style="width:200px">
    <span class="star">*</span>
       <span> C:\fakepath\996571_1398802860346752_2094565473_n.jpg</span>
    </div>


 .file-upload-status {
     text-align:right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
.star{
float:right;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mnevrs02/

Comment: solved the issue, but wanted to not use float:right;

Comment: not applicable.... this keeps the 3 dots at the end... not at the left