# Concatenate start of link with ellipsis

Tags: hyperlink, hide, display

How do I accomplish something like this:

[image: link concatenated]

The link is contained in a table cell, and the link should be extended (less of it hidden) when the cell is being extended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text-overflow ellipsis on left side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side)

Comment: That one didn't work for me. I was hoping for a very simple solution as well, not paragraphs of javascript if possible.