# Paragraph text to single line and display only last characters

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

In my program I have added to restrict paragraph text to single line display in CSS.

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
display: inherit;
```

But it display the initial words only. I want to display the last words of the paragraph when its overflow.

**Original Text:**

The purpose of Pattern Based Writing: Quick & Easy Essay is to quickly and easily teach students how to organize information and make points clear.

**Current Output:**

The purpose of Pattern Based Writing: Quick & Easy Essay is to quickly and easily teach studen..

**Expected Output:**

Essay is to quickly and easily teach students how to organize information and make points clear.

How to achieve this with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [Text-overflow ellipsis on left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793473/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-left-side)

HTML:

```
<p><bdi>The purpose of Pattern Based Writing: Quick & Easy Essay is to quickly and easily teach students how to organize information and make points clear.</bdi></p>
```

CSS:

```
p {  
  white-space: nowrap;                   
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
  width:550px;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Its working.. but another one issue will happening.  if the paragraph has numbers it will be align in right. for example: original text: 1. B2H : current text: B2H .1 which is wrong.

Comment: Put your content in a <bdi></bdi> tag. It will work!!

Comment: We aligned the text direction from right to left by 'rtl'. So, it thinks 1., 2., as list item index and moves index alone to right hand side.

Comment: Yes, <bdi> works! Have you tried it? Mark as answer if it helped. Thanks Sagar!

Comment: <bdi> tag works perfectly!.. Thanks @AshokanSivapragasam