# HTML & CSS - hide front part of string consisting of hashes and alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm presenting some sensitive alphanumeric data (imagine a hash or checksum) of variable length, out of which only last four characters should be visible to user, rest is replaced with '#' characters. It's placed in a table column, whose width might change, when the user resizes the browser window. Since the data is sometimes too long for the column, i'm supposed to hide the initial '#', so that only the relevant part is visible and as many '#' in front required to fill the column.

Now, i've found a couple of suggestions to use the trick with setting the following:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
direction:rtl;
text-align:left;
white-space: nowrap;                   
overflow: hidden;
```

eg:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9793669

Well, this is the efect:
http://jsfiddle.net/7qp8daj4/

Note, that for some reason the first string appears to start with the non-hash characters, followed by the hashes, while the second is presented correctly. By trial-and-error i managed to figure out that the "cause" is that the first string starts with a non-digit. If i replace the first line with eg `<span>##########1YH35</span>` it is displayed correctly.

Any ideas as to the cause or how to fix it? Or do you know any other cool solution for this requirement?

Comment: You should not be sending sensitive data the the client shouldn't see. JavaScript cannot secure this information.

Comment: Thanks for this note, but this is not the issue here. The problem is with displaying it correctly. I'm sending the masked version, eg. ##########1YH35

Comment: Why don't you just remove direction rtl?

Comment: The direction rtl is required to hide the front of the string using text-overflow ellipsis, instead of the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

After a brief discussion with a colleague i found a solution or a workaround: wrap the content with a  tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/grxLabq3/

```
<span><bdi>##########YH35</bdi></span>
<br/>
<span><bdi>##########8LHm</bdi></span>
```

With the same CSS:

```
span {  
  white-space: nowrap;                   
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow:    ellipsis;  
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:170px;
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:left;
}
```

It looks like the browser treats the first string as two seperate words or as a word and special characters and changes the order because of the direction setting.

I'm not 100% sure if this reasoning is correct and if it's the right way of doing this stuff, but looks okayish. Feel free to comment if anyone has any better idea :)